# Установка windows 98 на современный ноутбук

Tags: linux, windows, установка

Имеем: ноутбук corei5, 4gb оперативки два HDD по 500gb 1-й HDD:|100mb- зарезервировано системой||36gb- NTFS for Windows 7||390gb- NTFS (DATA)||40gb - прочие разделы Linux|2-й HDD:|465gb /home|

задача установить Windows 98 не повредив всего остального.

Т.к. 98 не дружит с NTFS думаю 2гига выдрать из (data). Потом может возникнуть проблема с несовместимостью оборудования (под "может возникнуть" я подразумеваю, что у меня вообще ничего не встанет, т.к. как минимум,  HDD у меня подключены через SATA, и имеют немаленькие размеры, к тому же мне не известно как оно заработает с современными процессорами, и как 98 относится к большому количеству ОЗУ? )

Если предположим я смогу как нибудь установить 98, что мне нужно сделать чтобы предварительно сохранить загрузочную запись, а потом восстановить её и добавить туда ещё и 98.

мне это необходимо для работы tasm. как вариант думаю установить чистый DOS в связке с FAR manager. DOS вроде как ещё жив, и используется где-то.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Зачем мучить мозг и комп, поставьте VirtualBox и поселите там Windows или что хотите

Comment: если бы оно так было просто :( через VB ни кто не может гарантировать стопроцентно корректной работы tasm

Comment: думаю, вы зря беспокоитесь. Виртуальная среда полностью изолирована

Comment: попробую установить на VB но мне всё равно не понятно как будет работать например команда "cli". позже отпишусь о результате

Comment: Проблем нет. Команда cli в виртуальной машине отрабатывает нормально, ведь нормально и полноценно эмулируется все "железо" компьютера.

Comment: а CapsLock и тд у меня загорятся интересно? Пока запара с виртуалкой чёта не создаёт новую машину. Ничего и до неё руки доберутся :)

Comment: При переключении фокуса на виртуальную машину - да, загорятся. Ну, или у виртуальной машины эти индикаторы могут отображаться где-то в окне интерфейса...

Answer (score 3):

Большая проблема именно с оперативной памятью... Намного проще Windows ME поставить. теоретически Windows 98 поддерживает 2гб оперативки но почему-то при загрузки она расценивает оперативную память и файл подкачки как одну общую в итоге если стоит 1гб оперативной памяти то она видет ее как 2. и не загружается, читал статью где Бета-тестор на стадии тестирования RC win98 поставил Windows на сервер с 1гб ОЗУ то она перестала загружаться (на сервере ОЗУ были по 16МБ) как только он вынимал 1 планку все начинало работать в норме. Он доложил о данной проблеме в Microsoft но те в ответ сказали что сроки релиза уже близко данной проблемой они не займутся и  кто будет ставить такое количество ОЗУ на PC.

Пути решения данной проблемы: их 3!

1я существует патч испарвляющий данный баг и позволяет работать с 2GB+ [Patch_win98se_for_full_memory_access.Multi (rus)](http://old-dos.ru/dl.php?id=1788)

Но проблема заключается в том что он ставится после того как установишь винду, как я делал брал старый компьютер PIII 1.4Ghz в котором 3*512мб ОЗУ (оставлял только 512мб) подключал HDD ставил туда win98, патчил и подключал уже к установленному компьютеру Intel Xenon 5450 c 4GB ОЗУ DDR3 все работало. Теоретически можно обойтись без таких махинаций если достать 1GB DDR3 (в природе я таких встречал но у меня не было в наличии, как вариант заказать у китайцев) отсоединить видеокарту и чтобы он запускался с интегрированной, тогда под видео память от основной отгрызется, и критический порог будет меньше. Но это только мое предположение и догадка!

2й вариант создать Live CD WIN98 (инструменты для его создания находятся образах лицензионного диска в папке TOOLS а инструкцию на русском языке на сайте Microsoft и она там до сих пор есть) с загрузочного диска я запускал на любой машине способ ПРОВЕРЕН на 100% с одним условием наличием раздела fat32 На HDD (нужен для хранения временных файлов и установки драйверов самой LIVE OS) как вариант улучшения записать данный образ не на CD а на флешку с FAT32 загрузочным разделом с помощью Программы UltraISO, но она не будет работать на всех компьютерах (все зависит от самого контроллера флешки, USB Контроллера на MB и драйверов) с USB 3.0 100% не катит.

3й вариант поставить вышеупомянутую Win ME до 2 ГБ поодерживат без проблем Сам ставил. как вариант можно поставить Поставить патч потом на 2GB+

P.S. Данные патчи не позволяют ОС Работать с большими обьемами ОЗУ а лишь ИГНОРИРОВТЬ наличие таковых. т.е. ОС будет использовать и резервировать меньше чем у вас установлено, не допуская критического придела. и 2е самое оптимально количество ОЗУ для Win98 3шт по 256 МБ ))))

Comment: вопрос был задан три года назад!!

Answer (score 2):

Не смешите - 4 гб оперативки. 98-я "винда" работает максимум с 512 мб оперативки и в этом вся проблема. Ставь на "виртуалку", выделяй 256 мб оперативки и вперед.

to ArcherGodson - это Вы мне объясняете? Я не нуждаюсь в Ваших разъяснениях. Читайте тему, ответы и давайте ответы топикстартеру, а не мне.

Comment: Когда создавали 98-ю "винду" о таком количестве оперативки и не мечтали :)))

Comment: XP тоже не тянет 4 гига, однако работает

Comment: "Тянет-не тянет" - я этого не понимаю. Я второй раз говорю: "98-я "винда" НЕ РАБОТАЕТ с оперативкой свыше 512 мб. Всё, точка. Третий раз повторять не буду. Если уж такой Фома-неверующий и предпочитаешь учиться на собственных ошибках, поставь на комп с оперативкой меньше 512 мб и увидишь результат, а проще на виртуалку. Да, кстати, не знаю почему, но VirtualBox у меня еле-еле тянет 98-ю, а продукты от M$ - прекрасно (virtualPC, VMware). Проверяй.

Comment: Да, ХР работает с оперативкой свыше 3,25 гиг, просто выше не видит, а работать будет прекрасно, а 98-я - не работает, уже при установке куча ошибок.

Comment: у меня есть XP x64, и она видит все 8 Гигов оперативы, так что XP видит оперативу, больше 3,2Г

Comment: Я говорил о 32-битной, но может лучше по теме: linux - Установка windows 98 на современный ноутбук?

Comment: это невозможно, и нет такой задачи, для которой понадобилась бы неподдерживаемая производителем система уже больше 10 лет.Лучший из предложенных вариантов - винда в виртуалке.

Answer (score 1):

Вот здесь статья про [Windows 98](http://nostalgy.net.ru/text/w98fsft.htm).

Правда, там больше речь о том, как сейчас установить её на средней старости компьютеры. А у вас новый ноутбук. Но может и пригодится что-то. Там ссылки на ресурсы любителей и энтузиастов 98 Винды, на всякие самодельные обновления и т.п.